# how to restore deleted user from profile database

Tags: user-profile

A user info was incorrect and profile sync was not updating. So I deleted the user from the user profile (Central admin). I did a full sync but that user did not make it in the profile database. How do I restore this deleted user back in the profile database.

Comment: hmm. Is there a way Add a user (just with the domain account) then run a incremental to update rest of the properties?

Answer (score 2):

Since it isn't really viable to restore a single profile, the easiest thing to do is to just recreate the User Profile through the User Profile Service Application.  Go into the Manage User Profiles section and create a new profile.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to restore deleted users instead you will have to restore the whole profile database. I would highly recommend laying a complete rollback plan before you proceed with restoration.

The only way to restore you users is to restore the previous back up of profile database. After restoration, reset the IIS and you are good to go!

But, if it is one user, it's better to create it manually.