# Deleted user profile from sharepoint, profile not picked from AD again

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

I have SharePoint 2010 configured to pick user profile details from AD. I had a user whose details were incorrectly picked by SharePoint. We have what you would define as 2 ADs. One for the parent company and one for ours. Basically the details were incorrectly entered in one AD and not the other.

I asked the administrators of AD to correct the details and ran a full synchronization once it was done. The details still havent been picked up. So I deleted the user profile from Sharepoint central administration thinking that they would be picked again. Alas, it isnt so.

Oh there is another point. We have two Sharepoint sites one for UAT and the other for Production. Each differs via port. After the full sync my UAT site picked the proper details in Sharepoint site designer but not the Production one.

What am I missing here?
Also disclaimer, I am new to SharePoint. All my knowledge is based upon reading articles only. I would appreciate ANY help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to add my comments as an answer. I am unable to add a comment at the moment.
I have run FULL SYNCHRONIZATION atleast 4 times in the past 2 days. The user email address was appearing incorrectly and so emails routed through Sharepoint would not reach them. In Sharepoint Designer when adding user to a group:

```
- In http://mysite:8800 (UAT) the details are propagated properly
- In http://mysite:8801 (Production) the old details are still appearing
```

Also to add, because I had deleted the profile of this user from Sharepoint in Central Administration, even AFTER running FULL SYNC the profile was not picked again. I have read here: [how to restore deleted user from profile database](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/how-to-restore-deleted-user-from-profile-database) that I may need to manually create the profile again. So I did and ran FULL SYNC AGAIN! Yet in Sharepoint Designer, the email address is not updated.

Update: A few hours later I checked again (without forcefully running the SYNC again) and the email address was updated in both places. I think some job is running in the background that I am unaware of. Now both 8800 and 8801 are up-to-date. I am relieved but would love to know how it managed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would restart the User Profile Sync Service via the Central Administration and then run a full sync again.
Double check your AD connection properties too.

While restarting the User Profile Sync service, you would need to have the farm account password handy. Then wait 5-10 minutes for it to start. If it does not start (stuck in 'starting') then you've got incorrect permissions on your APP box and and AD. 
Check my post on checking User Profile Sync permissions: http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2012/10/06/checking-the-user-profile-sync-permissions-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

you need to match the old user profile to the new profile(the changes been made on old userprofiles).

Can you pls let us know what are the details that are input incorrectly.

In your case you need to use the stsadm cmd for migrateuser.