# Recover/restore deleted user

Tags: user, onedrive-for-business

Is it possible to restore a user who got deleted from our SharePoint recently so I could get to the data that was being shared through his onedrive account?

Comment: You'd have to re-add the users manually or restore from a backup.

Comment: Thanks sir,Would Re-adding them relly restore all the files? could you also provide a quick ´how to´ for that?

Comment: re-adding them would not solve your problem I guess

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/how-to-restore-deleted-user-from-profile-database) with similar context which says:

It would be hard to restore deleted users instead you will have to restore the whole profile database. I would highly recommend laying a complete rollback plan before you proceed with restoration.

The only way to restore you users is to restore the previous back up of profile database. After restoration, reset the IIS and you are good to go!

But, if it is one user, it's better to create it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As the intent seems to be to get to the OneDrive files, why can't you just restore the Site Collection (assuming that a) it's been deleted and b) you have good backups).

You don't state whether your farm is on premises or O365 - my answer is relevant to on premises.  With O365 I don't believe there is an automatic delete so please check.

When the Site Collection is restored (or if it's already there), you will need to set yourself up as the Site Collection admin and go to
https://ONE_DRIVE_SITE/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx